# Flutter, can't extract api data : (Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.)

Tags: json, flutter, api

I want to get several JSON data from this api : *[www.themealdb.com](http://www.themealdb.com)* which use some classes. I've succeeded with the class Category but not with the main class "Meal".
I've this error on my debug console :

```
    [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Meal>(Closure: (dynamic) => Meal)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
#1      MealDBApi.featchMeal
package:gang_de_recettes/services/mealDB_api.dart:27
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      BlocMeal.fetchMealsByLetter
package:gang_de_recettes/blocs/bloc_meal.dart:17
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I'm new (it's my 1st question) when it comes to deserializing JSON objects so appreciate your help on this.

(Also I use BLoC pattern but there is not correlation with my problem)

This is a part of my JSON file pb (or : https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a)

```
{"meals":[{"idMeal":"52768","strMeal":"Apple Frangipan Tart","strDrinkAlternate":null,"strCategory":"Dessert","strArea":"British","strInstructions":"Preheat the oven to 200C\/180C Fan\/Gas 6.\r\nPut the biscuits in a large re-sealable freezer bag and bash with a rolling pin into fine crumbs. Melt the butter in a small pan, then add the biscuit crumbs and stir until coated with butter. Tip into the tart tin and, using the back of a spoon, press over the base and sides of the tin to give an even layer. Chill in the fridge while you make the filling.\r\nCream together the butter and sugar until light and fluffy. You can do this in a food processor if you have one. Process for 2-3 minutes. Mix in the eggs, then add the ground almonds and almond extract and blend until well combined.\r\nPeel the apples, and cut thin slices of apple. Do this at the last minute to prevent the apple going brown. Arrange the slices over the biscuit base. Spread the frangipane filling evenly on top. Level the surface and sprinkle with the flaked almonds.\r\nBake for 20-25 minutes until golden-brown and set.\r\nRemove from the oven and leave to cool for 15 minutes. Remove the sides of the tin. An easy way to do this is to stand the tin on a can of beans and push down gently on the edges of the tin.\r\nTransfer the tart, with the tin base attached, to a serving plate. Serve warm with cream, cr\u00e8me fraiche or ice cream.","strMealThumb":"https:\/\/www.themealdb.com\/images\/media\/meals\/wxywrq1468235067.jpg","strTags":"Tart,Baking,Fruity","strYoutube":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=rp8Slv4INLk","strIngredient1":"digestive biscuits","strIngredient2":"butter","strIngredient3":"Bramley apples","strIngredient4":"butter, softened","strIngredient5":"caster sugar","strIngredient6":"free-range eggs, beaten","strIngredient7":"ground almonds","strIngredient8":"almond extract","strIngredient9":"flaked almonds","strIngredient10":"","strIngredient11":"","strIngredient12":"","strIngredient13":"","strIngredient14":"","strIngredient15":"","strIngredient16":null,"strIngredient17":null,"strIngredient18":null,"strIngredient19":null,"strIngredient20":null,"strMeasure1":"175g\/6oz","strMeasure2":"75g\/3oz","strMeasure3":"200g\/7oz","strMeasure4":"75g\/3oz","strMeasure5":"75g\/3oz","strMeasure6":"2","strMeasure7":"75g\/3oz","strMeasure8":"1 tsp","strMeasure9":"50g\/1\u00beoz","strMeasure10":"","strMeasure11":"","strMeasure12":"","strMeasure13":"","strMeasure14":"","strMeasure15":"","strMeasure16":null,"strMeasure17":null,"strMeasure18":null,"strMeasure19":null,"strMeasure20":null,"strSource":null,"strImageSource":null,"strCreativeCommonsConfirmed":null,"dateModified":null},
```

My meal class where I only want to test the id, name & image url :

```
    class Meal {
  String idMeal;
  String strMeal;
  String strMealThumb;

  Meal(this.idMeal, this.strMeal, this.strMealThumb);

  Meal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : idMeal = json["idMeal"],
        strMeal = json["strMeal"],
        strMealThumb = json["strMealThumb"];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'idMeal': idMeal,
        'strMeal': strMeal,
        'strMealThumb': strMealThumb,
      };
}
```

My http request file :

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:gang_de_recettes/model/category.dart';
import 'package:gang_de_recettes/model/meal.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' show json;

class MealDBApi {
  final _baseUrl = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/";


  String _mealQueryBy1stLetter() => _baseUrl + "search.php?f=" + "a";
  String _allCategories() => _baseUrl + "categories.php";

  Future<List<dynamic>> request(String urlString, String key) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
    final result = await http.get(uri);
    final body = json.decode(result.body);
    //print("body :  ");
    //log(body.toString());
    return body[key];
  }

  Future<List<Meal>> featchMeal() async {
    List<dynamic> list = await request(_mealQueryBy1stLetter(), "");
    //print("listmeals : $list");
    return list.map((json) => Meal.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<Category>> fetchCategory() async {
    final List<dynamic> list = await request(_allCategories(), "categories");
    print("listctgry : $list");
    return list.map((json) => Category.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
}
```

And my bloc (but as I said, this is maybe not relevant) :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:gang_de_recettes/bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:gang_de_recettes/model/meal.dart';
import 'package:gang_de_recettes/services/mealDB_api.dart';

class BlocMeal extends Bloc {
  final _streamController = StreamController<List<Meal>>();
  Stream<List<Meal>> get stream => _streamController.stream;
  Sink<List<Meal>> get sink => _streamController.sink;

  BlocMeal() {
    fetchMealsByLetter();
  }

  fetchMealsByLetter() async {
    final meals = await MealDBApi().featchMeal();
    sink.add(meals);
  }


  @override
  dispose() => _streamController.close();
}
```

As I stated earlier, all of this, works for the class category for example.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe here

```
List<dynamic> list = await request(_mealQueryBy1stLetter(), "");
```

`list` will be null because your map has no key `""`
You probably wanted to do

```
List<dynamic> list = await request(_mealQueryBy1stLetter(), "meals")
```

Hopefully that is the problem and this fixes it